# mod_rewrite to index with displaying old URL

Tags: apache, mod-rewrite

I got a OHS (apache) and trying to do a redirect within a location:

My goal would be to redirect a call ...
on: http://example.com:23123/myApp/webapp-new/myApp_details
to: http://example.com:23123/myApp/webapp-new/index.html

But the Browser still should show the URL "http://example.com:23123/myApp/webapp-new/myApp_details"

Basical I got following that is mostly working ...

```
 <Location /myApp>
  SetHandler weblogic-handler
  WLLogFile /opt/myApp_logs/myApp.log
  Debug OFF
  WebLogicHost 127.0.0.1
  WebLogicPort 23123
  WLSocketTimeoutSecs 60

  RewriteEngine On
  RewriteBase /myApp
  RewriteRule  "(.*)/myApp_details$"  "/index.html"  [PT, L]
 </Location>
```

But this is redirecting/rewriting wrong or not. 
but tried as well:

```
  RewriteRule  "(.*)/myApp_details$"  "/index.html"  [PT, L]
  RewriteRule  "(.*)/myApp_details$"  "$1/index.html"  [PT, L]
  RewriteRule  "(.*)/myApp_details$"  "/index.html"  [PT, L]
```

... I got some: 404 Not found, Cant handle request or redirecting to wrong URL
what is the correct way of rewriting this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I finally solved it by following:

- moving the Rewrite Statements outside the Location section (recommended to not put it inside)
- did not user some regex/patterns (keep it simple)
- added following (no RewriteBase, exact URLs) (keep it simpler)

  ```
  RewriteEngine On
  RewriteRule  "/myApp/webapp-new/myApp_details"  "/myApp/webapp-new/index.html"  [PT,L]
  ```